# ASP.NET Core: using "DisplayFor" method in controller class to retrieve localized enum display attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an `enum` in my project like this:

```
 public enum Gender
 {
      [Display(Name="Gender.Male")]
      Male,

      [Display(Name="Gender.Female")]
      Female
 }
```

When I use the code below, it retrieves the name of `Gender` value from `.resx` files automatically and displays the translated value in razor view.

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Gender) //result: Männlich
```

but, how to get localized names of `Gender` values in the backend? or how to use `DisplayFor` or something like that in controller class?

```
 //Desired
 string gender = DisplayFor(x => x.Gender); //gender = "Männlich"
```

Should I code a new method instead of using `DisplayFor`?

Answer (score 1):

#### Get the name (or any other property) by code

```
// Example for a specifi value
string enumName = Gender.Male.GetType()
   .GetMember(Gender.Male.ToString())
   .SingleOrDefault()
   .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
   .GetName();
```

Now that you have the name, get it from the Resx using the [GetString(String, CultureInfo)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getstring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Resources_ResourceManager_GetString_System_String_System_Globalization_CultureInfo_) for  traditional .net, otherwise if you are using [Localizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.localization.istringlocalizer?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), then you can access it by the `Item[String]` property.